# filter multiple strings anywhere in one column values

Tags: r, filter, data-science, data-analysis

We have multiple columns in Data frame. In one column we have company name along with city name.
I wanted to filter data which has city name in the end of column value or anywhere.

**For example:input as like below**

TCS bangalore

Wipro global Bangalore

Bangalore consultant India private limited

Infosys chennai

systems bangalore pvt ltd

Manpower

Talent Delhi

Smart tech limited

HCL

Amazon Kochi

Paytm

India today

**Expected output**

TCS bangalore

Wipro global Bangalore

Bangalore consultant India private limited

Infosys chennai

systems bangalore pvt ltd

Manpower Hyderabad

Talent Delhi

Amazon Kochi

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a vector of all possible cities. For example:

```
cities <- c("Bangalore","Chennai","Delhi","Kochi","Mumbai","London","Madrid")
```

Then, assuming your data frame is called "data", with a column called "Company", the following command should return only rows where the Company contains one of the cities:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
filter(grepl(paste(cities, collapse="|"), Company))
```

The `grepl` function does the pattern matching for you.

Comment: Please show the output of `str(data)` where `data` is the name of your data frame.